# Risk Game not displaying score

Tags: vb6

I'm doing an assignment for my class called "Risk!", the basis of it is that you start with 1000 points, and input a number to risk. You roll 2 dice. If it's even, you lose and the input is removed from score. If it's odd, you win and input is added to score. For some reason, the score isn't displayed correctly.

```
Private Sub cmdQuit_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdRollDice_Click()
    intNumOutput1 = Int(Rnd * 6) + 1
    intNumOutput2 = Int(Rnd * 6) + 1

    lblNumOutput1.Caption = intNumOutput1
    lblNumOutput2.Caption = intNumOutput2

    intBothOutputs = intNumOutput1 + intNumOutput2

    If intBothOutputs Mod 2 > 0 Then
        intScore = intScore + intNumInput
        MsgBox "odd, win"
    Else
        intScore = intScore - intNumInput
        MsgBox "even, lose"
    End If

    lblTotal.Caption = "Your new point total is " & intScore
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Randomize
    Dim intScore As Integer
    Dim intNumOutput1 As Integer
    Dim intNumOutput2 As Integer
    Dim intBothOutputs As Integer
    Dim intNumInput As Integer

    txtNumInput.Text = intNumInput
    intScore = 1000

    txtNumInput.Text = ""
    lblNumOutput1.Caption = ""
    lblNumOutput2.Caption = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Describe the problem in more detail. What do you mean by "the score isnt displaying correctly"?

Comment: the score is display as "0" instead of 1000 originally, then plus or minus the input you risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For string concatenation its best practice to convert data types to string using cstr. e.g. CStr(intScore)
2. Add the event handler for txtNumInput. You have not assigned the value to intNumInput whenever button is clicked.

Try below.

```
Option Explicit

Private intScore As Integer
Private intNumOutput1 As Integer
Private intNumOutput2 As Integer
Private intBothOutputs As Integer
Private intNumInput As Integer

Private Sub cmdRollDice_Click()
  Dim intNumOutput1 As Integer
  Dim intNumOutput2 As Integer
  Dim intBothOutputs As Integer

  intNumOutput1 = Int(Rnd * 6) + 1
  intNumOutput2 = Int(Rnd * 6) + 1

  lblNumOutput1.Caption = intNumOutput1
  lblNumOutput2.Caption = intNumOutput2

  intBothOutputs = intNumOutput1 + intNumOutput2

  If intBothOutputs Mod 2 > 0 Then
    intScore = intScore + intNumInput
    MsgBox "odd, win"
  Else
    intScore = intScore - intNumInput
    MsgBox "even, lose"
  End If

  lblTotal.Caption = "Your new point total is " & CStr(intScore)
End Sub

Private Sub txtNumInput_Change()

  If IsNumeric(txtNumInput.Text) Then
    intNumInput = CInt(txtNumInput.Text)
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**When you want to use variables in more than one method (e.g. sub, function), you declare the variables outside of any method.**

Now, since you declared your variables inside `Form_Load`, you can't use them in `cmdRollDice_Click` or in any other method. So, what happens when you use them in a method other than the one they were declared in? Well, if you have `Option Explicit` statement on top of your code, you'll get a run-time error. If you don't (which is your current case), the variables will get initialized -with zero value- each time the method is called (*note: they're now not the same variables that were declared in `Form_Load`*).

Hence, you need to declare your variables on top of your file (before all functions/subs) like the following:

```
Dim intScore As Integer
Dim intNumOutput1 As Integer
Dim intNumOutput2 As Integer
Dim intBothOutputs As Integer
Dim intNumInput As Integer

' The rest of your code

Private Sub Form_Load()

End Sub

Private Sub cmdRollDice_Click()

End Sub
'
'
```

So, as a rule: you declare variables inside a method ONLY if you don't need to use them outside that method.

For more information about this, read [Understanding the Scope of Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231205(v=vs.60).aspx)

Hope that helps :)